# Discord : how to post a message in channels as a user

Tags: discord

I'm building an application connecting to Discord. Users can login with Oauth2.0 in the application. My application's goal is to post messages to the channel as a user, not a bot.

I've checked the documentation and the questions already asked, but I couldn't find a way to post as a user.
It would be nice to be APIs, but [`Execute Webhook`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message) and [`Create Message`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message) seem to be for bots.

Is there any API or other way to post to the channel as a user? If anyone knows, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Automating a user account is not allowed, see [this forum post](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) and [this section of the developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-vs-user-accounts)

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl  Hi, I had overlooked that description. Thanks for letting me know.